# jQuery UI Slider - Animation of handle and scroll content not in sync

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, jquery-animate, synchronization

Im having troubles getting the jQuery UI Slider customized for my purposes.

On load the slider and its content should automatically animate to a certain position. Ideally it should animate to the very right, then stop and then animate back (as a loop) as long as the user doesn't hovers over scroll content or slider.

Following my default slider setup (http://jsfiddle.net/mayko/j6WuE/1/):

```
var scrollbar = $("#slider").slider({
    animate: 3000,
    min: 0,
    max: $("#timeline_content .items").width(),
    change: handleSlider,
    slide: handleSlider
}); 
function handleSlider(e, ui) {
    $("#timeline_content").stop().animate({scrollLeft: ui.value}, scrollbar.slider("option", "animate"));
}
```

If i now try to set the value like this:

```
$('#slider').slider({'value': 1000});
```

The scroll content nicely animates, but the handle just jumps to that new position.

Even if I click on the slider track itself the animation of scroll content and slider handle are not in sync.

Does anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The "animate" option only applies to a click on the scrollbar. The animation is not triggered by setting a value manually as you have done.

In order to make the slider move you're going to either have to simulate user input (eg: trigger a click on the slider bar), or fake it with incremental value setting.

Unfortunately it seems that the slider does some funky stuff with the slider bar area, and I wasn't able to trigger a click there; you could try faking a click and drag on the slider maybe?

So the alternative is repeatedly setting the value of the slider, but it looks terrible.

```
function advanceSlider(next){
    scrollbar.slider('value',next)
        if(next<1050)
            setTimeout(function() { advanceSlider(next+50) },150);
}
advanceSlider(1);
```

Sorry, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6WuE/48/)

Comment: You are right. It looks horrible! What jQuery Ui tool could I use instead? Or does the jQuery Tools Lib got a better approach of dealing with sliders?